# Relation between non-degenerate bilinear forms and linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, bilinear-form

Let $V$ be a finite vector space over $\Bbb R$, let $q$ be an non-degenerate bilinear form. 
Let $T: V \to V$ be a linear transformation.

Prove that exists one and only one $S: V \to V$ so that $S$ is a linear transfomration satisfying:

$\forall v,w \in V \hspace{1.5mm} q(T(v), w) = q(v, S(w))$

My initial thought was to choose a Matrix $M$ that represents $q$ in some basis $C$ of $V$, and prove:

$[T(v)^t]_CM[w]_C \hspace{1.5mm} - [v^t]_CM[S(w)^t]_C = 0$

Obviously, if $M$ is positive-definite then we can take $S$ to be $T^*$ and we achieve the desired result since $q$ is an inner product. However, if $M$ is not definite-positive, I'm not sure how to tackle this - mainly unsure how to use the fact that $M$ is invertible. Any help is appreciated very much.

Comment: You quantify over a $\forall u\in V$, but then the rest of the statement only uses $v$ and $w$. Then later you use just $u$ and $v$. I can't quite tell if that was intentional.

Comment: My bad, I am not sure why but I got mixed up on my own notations. There should be only $v$ and $w$ throughout the question. I'll edit it right now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof that is coordinate free.

**Existence**  Since $q$ is nondegenerate, given $w\in V$ there is a unique $u\in V$ such that for every $v\in V$, $q(T(v),w) = q(v,u)$. I leave this for you to check.

Thus, we can define a map $S:V\to V$ by $S(w) = u$.  Combining the fact that $T$ is linear and $q$ is bilinear, you can prove that $S$ is linear: For all $v\in V$,

$$q(v,S(\alpha w_1 + w_2)) = q(T(v),\alpha w_1 + w_2) = q(T(v),\alpha w_1) + q(T(v),w_2) $$
$$ = q(\alpha T(v), w_1) + q(v,S(w_2)) = q(T(\alpha v), w_1) + q(v,S(w_2)) = q(\alpha v, S(w_1)) + q(v,S(w_2))$$
$$= q(v,\alpha  S(w_1)) + q(v,S(w_2)) = q(v,\alpha S(w_1) + S(w_2)).$$
Thus,
$$S(\alpha w_1 + w_2) = \alpha S(w_1) + S(w_2)$$
by nondegeneracy of $q$, so $S$ is linear.

**Uniqueness** This is easy. Supppose you have two such transformations $S$ and $S'$ and use nondegeneracy of $q$ to prove they are equal (as transformations).

Answer (score 0):

Using your approach we obtain, thinking of $T$ and $S$ as square matrices,
$$v^t T^t M w = v^t M S w \quad \textrm{for all }v, \, w,$$
so we must have $T^t M = M S$. This implies, using the fact that $M$ is invertible, $$S = M^{-1} T^t M.$$

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you think there are different approaches to this questions, without resorting to the matrix that represents the bilinear form?